# Redirect to a custom phtml file from a controller in Magento?

Tags: redirect, magento-1.4, php

I have a Magento controller and a phtml file. How can I redirect to that file in my controller action? I searched the net, but found nothing. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424179/how-do-i-link-to-another-action-in-magento-whilst-passing-a-parameter-to-the-new

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to show the contents of your phtml-file when visiting the URL of the controller, you should follow this tutorial: [Baobaz Controller Tutorial](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/tag/magento-controller)
It has everything in it you need. Even interaction between the controller and the template.
Remember to adjust the paths and class names to your solution.