# How do I link to another action in Magento whilst passing a parameter to the new page (controller) as a POST link and not a query string?

Tags: magento

I need to pass a parameter to a new page (without query strings), because I would like to redirect back to the module and query string of the current page.

So I can get from

1. showdown/index?id=35 --click---> showdown/vote?id=1
2. showdown/vote?id=1 --redirect--> showdown/index?id=35

The vote action is not seen.

*(The redirect method doesn't work as it redirects to the plain index.php homepage url only and not keeping the module/action intact, and I cannot find a helper in Magento for creating hyperlinks.)*

Does Magneto have a link helper for this?

Example of stuff I want: `<a href="<?php echo Mage::Helper->Link->($url, $array); ?>` then $array or whatever variables gets sent to the controller (page I linked to).

Can I use a POST style hyperlink? *(I can in Symfony/Yii/Rails/Ramaze frameworks. Why not Zend?)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link clicks will not result in a POST request without JavaScript.

Magento Url helper has the syntax

> `Mage::getUrl('module/controllerfile/action',array('id',1))`

which would result in a lookup of the frontName for `module` and would give you for example

> http://site.com/module/controllerfile/action/id/1/

which you could then access with `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')`.

If you have multiple URLs involved (like a form post), you can also redirect the user within the controller by using

> `$this->_redirect('module/controllerfile/action', array('id',1))`

You can also create a query string with

> `$this->_redirect('module/controllerfile/action', array('_query',array('param1'=>'val','param2'=>'val')))`.

Comment: I can't use `http://site.com/module/controllerfile/action/id/1/` because it fails on my site. Check here. http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/showdown/index?view=2 works and http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/showdown/index/view/2 fails. Do you know why? Without having this fixed, I cannot ever have `getUrl` to work.

Comment: http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/showdown/index/index/view/2 - try using `_redirect('showdown/index/index')`

Comment: But the number of the array key keeps appearing in the url. `Mage::getUrl('showdown/index/vote',array('c'))` becomes `http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/index.php/showdown/index/vote/0/c/` I do not want `vote/0/c/` I only want `vote/c` If I make it `array('c', 'd')` I end up with `vote/0/c/1/d` Please help!

Comment: `Mage::getUrl('showdown/index/vote',array('id'=>'c'))` is what you want. This will give the URL `http://desbest.uk.to/clients/magentofull/index.php/showdown/index/vote/id/c/`. In your `voteAction()` method you would access the value via `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')`.